# Programm type already exist: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzd /android studio

Tags: java, android

Hello as you can see i got a little problem there with the ....internal.zzd

I watched YT Videos or google how to fix that after 4 Days i gave up and cried in my shower. Now i need you guys to help me by solve this problem.

Here is my dependencies in my gradle build:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'



}
```

Answer (score 0):

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:**play-services-ads**:17.0.0'
>
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:**play-services**:12.0.1'

probably, the one below already contains the one above, therefore, you have 2 of the mentioned class

also, 
["Note: Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses."](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)